# Menu aside on mobile - js target

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design

I have created a website and I have uploaded it to the server. You can check this website on URL address: https://olczanskidom.pl. My problem is that I've created a menu on mobile and when the menu is open you can click anywhere outside the menu to close it. On my mac browser everything is working perfect, but on iPhone X or 6s, it brings me an issue. I can only close menu after click on any header images or any photo in the gallery, on any other targets menu is not closing. What can do this issue on mobile and on mac can work perfect ??

```
click = e => {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('menu')) {
      this.setState({
        showMenu: false
      });
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.click);
    }
  };
```

I'm fireing event on any target that doesn't have class menu

Comment: Could you try adding the CSS Property 'cursor: pointer' to the element that the user clicks to close the menu? This issue might be related https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2055

Comment: Watch code and comment how can i do this

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some mobile browsers if the user taps body, then no click event will trigger. A solution is to use a container which will be wrapped around your menu. The container would be a div, width and height 100%, transparent in appearance and would have a click event.

This click event would fire successfully and you could hide the container.